How to Automatically Configure OPNsense on an AWS EC2 Instance to Manage NAT within a VPC
I'm trying to set up an AWS EC2 instance with OPNsense that automatically configures itself to handle NAT (Network Address Translation) within my AWS VPC. My goal is to have OPNsense manage this function without requiring manual configuration after the instance starts.
I've looked into using the user data script to apply a default configuration when the EC2 instance launches, but I'm not sure how to set this up. Is it possible to automate the OPNsense configuration in this way? If so, could someone provide an example or point me in the right direction?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

I'm in a rush, but since you haven't received a reply yet, I can help you get started. Here's what I would do:

Create the necessary image in a VM locally using VMware or VirtualBox.

Import the VMDK or VHD to AWS AMI using the AWS CLI.

Launch an EC2 instance from this AMI.

Configure and test the setup. If everything works well, export a backup configuration from Opnsense and version it somewhere.

From that versioning, create a pipeline using GitLab CI or GitHub Actions. The pipeline would utilize AWS CLI to SSH into your EC2 and upgrade the configs.


If you're a company, you might find a better fit with the ami from opnsense (30 days free trial).
